# Azure ADB2C Upload to blob storage error

Tags: c#, azure, xamarin.forms, azure-storage, azure-active-directory

I try to upload my html page to Azure blob storage for my Azure b2c, but whenever I tried to upload the file, I keep getting this error:

```
Azure AD B2C Blob Storage Helper Tool

This tool will upload all contents of a directory to an Azure Blob Storage Container you specify.  
It will also enable CORS access from all origins on each of the files.

Enter your Azure Storage Account name:
sample  

Enter your Azure Blob Storage Primary Access Key:  
***==  

Enter your Azure Blob Storage Container name:  
https://sample.blob.core.windows/sample  

Enter the path to the directory whose contents you wish to upload:  
C:\Users\admin\Downloads\B2C-AzureBlobStorage-Client-master\B2C-AzureBlobStorage-Client-master\sample_templates\wingtip
```

> Error Making Request to Azure Blob Storage:
>
> The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.
>   Press Enter to close...

Did I make a mistake in here? Or is there error in the storage helper tool? I Already follow al the tutorial from here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-reference-ui-customization-helper-tool

Comment: Have you tried creating a container manually on azure portal? It has some limitations on what name you can give containers.

For example: Container name cannot contain upper case letters.

If you request a container with an invalid name, it will result in (400) Bad Request, which you are getting. **So check your "containerName" string**

Comment: yeah i create the container manualy, with lower case

Comment: Can you share the name of the container you're trying to create? Also, please tell the redundancy type of the storage account (i.e. is it LRS, GRS, etc.?).

Comment: here is my redundancy Read-access geo-redundant storage (RA-GRS). and i already tried to make new storage account , my container name is b2c and my storage account name is kgvc3

Comment: @TheodorusAgumGumilang You should enter your container name not url, I test in my lab, if I enter url, I get same error log with you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Enter your Azure Blob Storage Container name:

You should enter your container name not URL.

Please replace `https://sample.blob.core.windows/sample` to `sample`.